# How do I specify a Bayesian Beta binomial model, with predictor variables, for R2jags?

Tags: r, bayesian, jags, beta-binomial-distribution

I want to have a beta-binomial Bayesian model, with `R2jags`. I understand I need something like this:

```
    for (i in 1:N) {
      y[i] ~ dbinom(p,n[i])
      p ~ dbeta(a,b)
    }
```

Now suppose I have 2 types of subjects in my observations y, and I want to know whether 'type' makes a difference to p. I imagine I need some way to make a and b depend on my covariate 'type'. How is this done?

Answer (score 4):

It is not really a *"how to code it in JAGS"* problem, but it is about defining the appropriate model for your data. If you want to include predictor variables for your data, this means you need a [regression model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/173660/definition-and-delimitation-of-regression-model/211229#211229). This means that you need something like

```
  for (i in 1:N) {
    y[i] ~ dbinom(p[i], n[i])
    logit(p[i]) <- REGRESSION MODEL DEFINITION
  }
```

Check [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/28609/regularized-bayesian-logistic-regression-in-jags) for one example.

Regarding your comment, you could use a hierarchical model including a lower-level [beta regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29038/regression-for-an-outcome-ratio-or-fraction-between-0-and-1) model, i.e. something like

```
  for (i in 1:N) {
    y[i] ~ dbinom(p[i], n[i])
    p[i] ~ dbeta(alpha[i], beta[i])
    alpha[i] = phi[i] * mu[i]
    beta[i] = phi[i] * (1 - mu[i])
    logit(mu[i]) <- REGRESSION MODEL DEFINITION
    phi[i] ~ SOME PRIOR
  }
```

Comment: Thank you. I had tried something along those lines, but I find that the binomial does not give me enough variance. Gelman (DBA, p 438) suggests using the beta-binomial, with -in my case- a different probability for each group, drawn from a beta distribution.

Comment: @Old_Mortality check my edit.